# newlfm expect new fancyhdr.sty but it's the newest

Tags: errors, fancyhdr, templates, newlfm

I want to convert [this template](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/long-lined-cover-letter) with `pdflatex` to PDF but `newlfm` expects [`fancyhdr.sty`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) to be current version. Installed is the newest version 4.0.1. How can this error be fixed or is it a bug?

```
! Class newlfm Error: Version of fancyhdr.sty is not current.
(newlfm)              Please obtaina recent copy of fancyhdr.sty (Version 1.99d
 or later) from CTAN..

See the newlfm class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.44 ...ad the current version of fancyhdr.sty}}{}
                                                  %
? H
Go to CTAN anddownload the current version of fancyhdr.sty
?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an issue with an outdated [`newlfm`](//ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) class. However, it's fairly easy to recreate the layout provided by the template. And, as a personal preference, the code is far more clear in terms of the layout if you avoid using `newlfm` (which hasn't been updated in more than a decade).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter} % Use the Charter font for the document text

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx}

\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}%
  % Add more detail here if needed
}
\fancypagestyle{otherpages}{%
  \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}%
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}%
  % Add more detail here if needed
}

\AtBeginDocument{\thispagestyle{firstpage}}
\pagestyle{otherpages}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\dimexpr-\headsep-\headheight-1pt}

\includegraphics[width=2.1in]{logo.png}

\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}

\bigskip\bigskip

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ l @{} }
  \today \\[12pt] % Date
  123 Broadway \\ % Address
  City, State 12345 \\
  Phone: (000) 111-1111 \\
  Email: john@smith.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ @{} l }
  Mrs.\ Jane Smith \\ % Addressee of the letter above the to address
  Recruitment Officer \\ % To address
  The Corporation \\
  123 Pleasant Lane \\
  City, State 12345
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Mrs.\ Smith,

\bigskip

PARAGRAPH ONE: State the reason for the letter, name the position or type of work you are applying for and identify the source from which you learned of the opening (i.e. career development center, newspaper, employment service, personal contact).

PARAGRAPH TWO: Indicate why you are interested in the position, the company, its products, services - above all, stress what you can do for the employer. If you are a recent graduate, explain how your academic background makes you a qualified candidate for the position. If you have practical work experience, point out specific achievements or unique qualifications. Try not to repeat the same information the reader will find in the resume. Refer the reader to the enclosed resume or application which summarizes your qualifications, training, and experiences. The purpose of this section is to strengthen your resume by providing details which bring your experiences to life. 
 
PARAGRAPH THREE: Request a personal interview and indicate your flexibility as to the time and place. Repeat your phone number in the letter and offer assistance to help in a speedy response. For example, state that you will be in the city where the company is located on a certain date and would like to set up an interview. Alternatively, state that you will call on a certain date to set up an interview. End the letter by thanking the employer for taking time to consider your credentials. 

\bigskip

Sincerely yours,

\vspace{50pt}

John Smith

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, though I have an issue with `\includegraphics[width=2.1in]{logo.png}` it does not work. I tried it with the original code `\includegraphics[width=1.2\linewidth]{logo.png}}}` and works neither. How can this be fixed?

Comment: @sdf: I downloaded `logo.png` from the template. You need that in your working folder.

Comment: Yes done but says `! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in logo.png (no BoundingBox).` in line 31.

Comment: @sdf: You're probably compiling with LaTeX. Change to compile with pdfLaTeX (in OverLeaf, click on Menu in the top-left corner, then change the compiler to pdfLaTeX).

Comment: Yes,  running (pdf)LaTeX in DVI mode, which requires explicitly setting the bounding box for image files. Changed to pdflatex and  works.

Answer (score 6):

`fancyhdr` has renamed several of its internal commands to get a more consistent naming scheme. `newlfm` uses an outdated command name to check if `fancyhdr` is outdated. Back in 2009 that worked, nowadays it doesn't. But even if you remove the check from `newlfm`, it won't work because it uses a couple of internal `fancyhdr` commands that have also got new names. Anyway, I wouldn't recommend using internal commands from `fancyhdr`, and I think `newlfm` could be rewritten without them.

My first advise is to go with @Werner's solution.

If `newlfm` is a requirement, there are two solutions:

1. Get an old version of `fancyhdr`. The last one that will work with `newlfm` is V3.8, which can be found at [Github](https://github.com/pietvo/fancyhdr/releases/tag/V3.8). But this is not the recommended solution, just a stopgap.
2. Make a patched copy of `newlfm.cls`. I think the following patch will work.

```
diff -u newlfm.cls.orig newlfm.cls
--- newlfm.cls.orig 2021-02-18 11:29:10.000000000 +0100
+++ newlfm.cls  2021-02-18 11:38:36.000000000 +0100
@@ -38,10 +38,6 @@
 \RequirePackage{eso-pic}%
 \RequirePackage{setspace}%
 \RequirePackage{lastpage}%
-\@ifundefined{ps@@empty}{%
-  \ClassError{newlfm}{Version of fancyhdr.sty is not current. \MessageBreak Please obtain%
-    a recent copy of fancyhdr.sty (Version 1.99d or later) from CTAN.}  {Go to CTAN and%
-    download the current version of fancyhdr.sty}}{}%
 \RequirePackage{calc}[1997/11/11]%
 \RequirePackage{graphicx}[1997/06/09]%
 \RequirePackage{rotating}[1997/06/09]%
@@ -1687,13 +1683,13 @@
 \txa{@zpqutil:\@zpqutil}
 \fi
 }
-\newcommand{\@zfancyhead}[5]{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset
+\newcommand{\@zfancyhead}[5]{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\f@nch@reset
   \@zfancyvbox\headheight{\hbox
     {\rlap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2}}\hfill
       \parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\centering#3}\hfill
       \llap{\parbox[b]{\headwidth}{\raggedleft#4}}}\zheadrule}}#5}
 
-\newcommand{\@zfancyfoot}[5]{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\fancy@reset
+\newcommand{\@zfancyfoot}[5]{#1\hbox to\headwidth{\f@nch@reset
     \@zfancyvbox\footskip{\zfootrule
       \hbox{\rlap{\parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\raggedright#2}}\hfill
         \parbox[t]{\headwidth}{\centering#3}\hfill
@@ -2144,7 +2140,7 @@
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  \vspace*{\the\@marg@tp@a}
 \txa{headrulewidth:\headrulewidth}
-\@zfancyhead{\relax}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@ncyolh}{\f@ncyorh}{\relax}
+\@zfancyhead{\relax}{\f@nch@olh}{\f@nch@olh}{\f@nch@orh}{\relax}
 \txa{HgtHead:\the\@Hgt@Head,utill:\the\@utill,zpqutil:\@zpqutil}
 \addtolength{\@Hgt@Head}{\@utill}
 \addtolength{\@Hgt@Head}{\@zpqutil}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the referenced `fancyhdr` version from GitHub doesn't play well with newlfm: `! Undefined control sequence. \@zfancyhead ...1\hbox to\headwidth {\f@nch@reset `

Comment: The patch did work though! To save time for future generations of poor newlfm users, here's the resulting newlfm.cls, that you can put in the directory with your tex file using the class: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ulysses4ever/f23c3926ec6f79f6fbfaa545fd73ee5e/raw/11951138389ca854703628539d7b992b74b97932/newlfm.cls

Comment: The next release of `fancyhdr` (version 4.1) will add support for `newlfm` that will eliminate the errors.

Answer (score 2):

Some great answers are above, [Werner's](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/583808/269571) being the most versatile.

However, if you are looking for a quick fix, check if the pdf is being created by the compiler. If yes, comment out line nos. 41 through 44 of `newlfm.cls` file.

Clicking on the error takes you to the condition that throws this error. I tried this on an off-line compiler (TeXstudio as editor). Note that GNU license requires you to save the .cls as a separate file.